# Can I generate Eclipse / Xcode Projects Using Mono for Android or MonoTouch repectively?

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, monodevelop

I am planning to buy MonoTouch and Mono for Android, but before I do I just want to know whether I can generate complete Xcode/Eclipse Projects from Mono the way we can do it in Titanium Studio. When we build the Titanium project it generates Java Projects for Ecplise and Objective-C code for Xcode.

Is the same process available in Mono? So that when I run into any limitations I can continue working on the project as a native project.

Comment: Xamarin's design is not the same as Titanium Studio, and it is meaningless to generate such projects if you use MonoTouch or Mono for Android. I can hardly agree "a native project" is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

There are no supported ways of generating Eclipse / Xcode projects with Mono for Android / MonoTouch.

In any case it's not something you'd want to do:

- An Eclipse project for Mono for Android would be very little Java code, just a bunch of binary files compiled / bundled together by build commands in project file.
- MonoTouch would spit out code, but it would be assembly, not ObjectiveC (and quite a few binary files too). I can hardly see how that would be interesting...